# CREATE TABLE - Works in MySQL but not in Bash

Tags: mysql, sql, database, bash, create-table

I'm writing a `bash` script that connects to `mysql` and creates a database as follows:

`mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE test;"`

I see the database gets created using the following command:

`mysql -u root -e "SHOW databases;"`

Which outputs:

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
| test               |
+--------------------+
```

Now I wish to `USE` this newly created database and `CREATE TABLE`, hence I run this code:

```
mysql -u root -e "USE test;"
mysql -u root -e "SELECT DATABASE();"
mysql -u root -e "CREATE TABLE information (id bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(128), value_one int(255), value_two int(255), value_three int(255), value_four int(255), value_five bigint, value_six bigint);"
```

In order for me to see which database is selected, the `SELECT DATABASE();` statement returns:

```
+------------+
| DATABASE() |
+------------+
| NULL       |
+------------+
```

The `CREATE TABLE` statement gives me this error:

```
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 1: No database selected
```

Alternatively, I tried joining these together:

`mysql -u root -e "USE test; CREATE TABLE information (...);"`

With no exit at all. I still get the same error.

Given that `mysql` supports a connection to the database directly in the command:

`mysql test -u root -e "CREATE TABLE information (...);"`

Or as per this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033648/how-to-run-mysql-command-on-bash):

`mysql --database=test -u root -e "CREATE TABLE information (...);"`

They didn't work for me either.

Does someone know why I cannot create a table?

Any help is appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**

According to @Genuine 's answer, it actually works in `mysql` but I cannot manage to run the query through `bash`. Here is what `mysql` looks like from the terminal:

[image]

I've done lots of reading about how to connect the `bash` script to the according database, and I reiterate that this should work:

`mysql -u root -e "USE test; CREATE TABLE information (...);"`

But it doesn't and still shoots the `ERROR 1046 (3D000)`.

Is something wrong my `bash` syntax?

It's also worth mentioning that @Genuine pointed out the correct syntax:

`USE test; SELECT DATABASE();`

Which now displays:

```
+------------+
| DATABASE() |
+------------+
| test       |
+------------+
```

---

**Note**: The above script snippets are written sequentially, meaning that I first `CREATE DATABASE test;`, then `USE test;` and lastly `CREATE TABLE information (...);`. My latest connection is through `root@127.0.0.1` and I essentially utilise **Sequel Pro** to help me test my queries first.

Answer (score 4):

`select database();` only can show the current database which is used. In `shell`, each of them is a separate statement，they are not in one session, so you can't use sql like that.
If you want to show what you want you can use sql like `use test;select database()`
[image]

And `mysql -u root -e "USE test; CREATE TABLE information (...);"` can work in my database, maybe you should check your sql firstly.
[image]

Comment: You are right, `mysql` does execute `USE test; SELECT DATABASE();` correctly, however, `USE test; CREATE TABLE information (...)` still gives me the same error.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to debug this? @Genuine

Comment: you can execute your `create table` in mysql to check if your sql is correct. It dose execute correctly in my mysql, so it should be worked.

Comment: Well it works in `mysql`, but I cannot make it work in `bash` @Genuine

Comment: Yes @Genuine I updated my question with an image of my `shell`